# awaiting AcceptTcpClientAsync() breaks out of while loop

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, tcp

I'm trying to build a simple multi client TCP server. I have a async function called by the main program that runs into a while loop, awaiting Clients to connect. My problem is that the program never moves past the await (which is expected with no client connecting) and just ends itself.

```
    public async void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            Listener.Start();
            Running = true;
            while (Running)
            {
                var client = await Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                await Task.Run(() => HandleConnection(client, token));
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

There are no excpetions thrown, Debugging just ends. I don't understand how the program is leaving the infinite while loop.

Comment: The exception is being captured and not display inside one of the methods. The application is then exiting.  In c# you do not always get a displayed exception when an error occurs.

Comment: From my understanding this catch block `catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }` 

should catch any excpetion that might occur, shouldn't it? It ends just the same way. Even removing the try block entirely doesn't throw any error.

Comment: I suspect that you don't have any other threads running any useful operations and you're letting yourself return from your `Main` - which means you've got no threads doing anything and the process exits. A simple fix would be to make this `async Task` instead and let that flow up until you become `async Main` or you end up actually blocking a real thread.

Comment: Not if the exception is being called in a child method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suspect that you don't have any other threads running any useful
> operations and you're letting yourself return from your Main - which
> means you've got no threads doing anything and the process exits. A
> simple fix would be to make this async Task instead and let that flow
> up until you become async Main or you end up actually blocking a real
> thread. - Damien_The_Unbeliever

This was the problem.